# error occurs at second run

Tags: iphone

Im developing a little navigation based application. Part of the programe, It passes CGpoint value to its superclass. There is no problem on the first attempt but error always occurs when re run the same process right after first execution. Is this because about memory management? I just dont get what I have done wrong.

delegation from child

```
[self.delegate sendPosition:position];
```

method on Rootclass

```
-(void) sendPosition:(CGPoint)position{

        dLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",position.x];
}
```

Comment: The code you have written seems fine. The only thing I can think of is that maybe you are calling that method too frequently, or are passing it bad data? Maybe post a bit more code for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delegate is not the same as a super class. I'm guessing your delegate disappears but you are still calling it later. Go over your memory management indeed. Make sure that the delegate is still around, or sticks around, or nullify delegate properties if you need to destroy the delegate instance for some reason.

Comment: oh, after I commented out [childClass release], it works fine, but I kind of worry is this right thing to do. may be thats because I dont understand well. I'm sorry to ask you but could you please explain me what does it mean by 'delegate is around'? because I thought I did releasing and create the same thing as first time so there will be no problem.